# Webclient not wiring up kotlin Spring boot and returns null object

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, oauth, webclient

I have declared `OAuthClientConfiguration` setting for `WebClient` using `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository`. But when I try to autowire the `WebClient` bean it does not pick up the configuration settings of `OAuthClientConfiguration` and returns null object.

`OAuthClientConfiguration` defines as follows:

```java
@Configuration
class OAuthClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun clientRegistrations(
        @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta.access-token-url}") access_token: String?,
        @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-id}") client_id: String?,
        @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-secret}") client_secret: String?,
        @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope}") scope: String?,
        @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.authorization-grant-type}") authorizationGrantType: String?
    ): ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository? {
        val registration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("okta")
            .tokenUri(access_token)
            .clientId(client_id)
            .clientSecret(client_secret)
            .scope(scope)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType(authorizationGrantType))
            .build()
        return InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration)
    }

    @Bean
    fun webClient(clientRegistrations: ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository?): WebClient? {
        val clientService = InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations)
        val authorizedClientManager =
            AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService)
        val oauth = ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager)
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("okta")
        return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth)
            .build()
    }
}
```

And `WebClient` calling is defined as follows:

```java
@Autowired
private var webClient: WebClient? = null


fun getAccessToken(): String? {
    return webClient?.post()
        ?.retrieve()
        ?.bodyToFlux(String::class.java)
        ?.onErrorMap { e: Throwable? -> Exception("message", e) }
        ?.blockLast();
}
```

How to create `WebClient` with configuration defined in `OAuthClientConfiguration` class?

I want it to be wired up so that the configuration defined in `OAuthClientConfiguration` could be setup as I initialise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the client is created correctly. However, the wiring seems wrong.

As a rule of thumb, it is better practice to wire on the constructor

```
@Service
class MyService(
    val webClient: WebClient
)
```

Alternative, in Kotlin, I usually use:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var webClient: WebClient
```

Comment: When I autowire using lateinit, its gives an error: 

lateinit property webClient has not been initialized

Comment: I'm assuming that you are in a class annotated as a Component and in a subpackage to the main class. Correct?
But, again, you should use it in constructor instead.

Comment: Yes, I have annotated it as a Component and in a subpackage to the main class. 
I cannot use it in constructor because i am calling it from another class.

Comment: What do you mean you are calling it from another class? Are you creating the class with a `new` ?